# A Good Tool For Drawing Tree

Tags: software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for “relationship graphs”](https://superuser.com/questions/53789/software-for-relationship-graphs)

Is there any good tool for drawing trees similar to those found in data structure books?
I have searched Google but all of the tools like Visio, Dia, are general tools and drawing trees with them takes too much time.

Comment: If you could link to an example screenshot, that would be most awesome. I have a difficult time knowing exactly what you mean by "tree" (mindmap, decision "tree" (flow diagram), etc.).

Answer (score 3):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a processor from text to a picture.  You type in code in a text editor, and it generates a tree/graph for you.  See also [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) and [guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf).

In the text you write, you specify how the nodes relate to each other (child -> parent), and then graphviz tries to draw it as neatly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a tool for drawing graphs (every tree is a graph), then you might check out [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html). It supports directed and undirected, and has many options for configuration.